# populating core data model through JSON with multiple Entities

Tags: ios, xcode, json, core-data

Having an issue populating a core data model with two entities through a JSON file,

I managed to populate the first entity with no issues, but once i tried populating the second entity, received an error stating the data parameter is nil,

Ive checked that I've used the correct json file name (Weights.json).

Below is the code:

```
 // Create the managed object context
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();
    // Save the managed object context
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error while saving %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    NSError* err = nil;
    NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Exercises" ofType:@"json"];
    NSArray* exercisesFromJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:&err];
    //NSLog(@"Imported exercisesFromJSON: %@", exercisesFromJSON);


    [exercisesFromJSON enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *exerciseDictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        Exercise *exercise = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise"
                                                           inManagedObjectContext:context];
        NSDictionary *attributes = [[exercise entity] attributesByName];
        for (NSString *attribute in [attributes allKeys]) {
            id value = [exerciseDictionary objectForKey:attribute];
            if (value == nil) {
                continue;
            }
            [exercise setValue:value forKey:attribute];
        }
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];

    NSString* secondDataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Weights" ofType:@"json"];
    NSArray* weightsFromJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:secondDataPath]
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:&err];


  ///***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'****//////
    NSLog(@"Imported weightsFromJSON: %@", weightsFromJSON);


    [weightsFromJSON enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *weightDictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        Weight *weight = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Weight"
                                                           inManagedObjectContext:context];
        NSDictionary *attributes = [[weight entity] attributesByName];
        for (NSString *attribute in [attributes allKeys]) {
            id value = [weightDictionary objectForKey:attribute];
            if (value == nil) {
                continue;
            }
            [weight setValue:value forKey:attribute];
        }
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
```

thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't think we have enough info to help.  Can you post more about your object model and the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: object model consists of two entities (Exercise and Weight) with their on attributes. Aim of the code is to populate both these entities through two JSON files (Exercises.json and Weights.json).

Comment: Exception occurs after the NSArray* weightsFromJSON line, exception has been edited into the code above.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you're not loading your data and the call to `JSONObjectWithData` is failing.  From the docs on `dataWithContentsOfFile:` "Return Value
A data object by reading every byte from the file specified by path. Returns nil if the data object could not be created."

Comment: i do not seem to understand why it is failing to load, there is no issue when compiling code for just one entity...

Comment: It's not about your entities, it's about your app not finding your "Weights.json" data file.  You probably forgot to add it to your target, so it's not getting copied over with the bundle.  Check that first.  If that's not the issue, then use `dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:` and check the error returned from it--that will tell you why you couldn't load data from the file.

Comment: Thanks it was the target...i set the target of the new file upon creation but forgot to actually copy the file in.